# Snowflake Stream became stale even though data is coming through

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've set up a few streams and tasks that consume these streams in Snowflake and at times I need to recreate them because they became stale. I've read through the documentation and there is nothing in my account that causes the issue. The tasks are running every 5 minutes and there is data flowing through every minute. The task scripts take the data in the streams and use a `MERGE` statement. At times the stream just becomes stale and then the task starts failing.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: An example of the task code would be good. Usually streams become stale due to data retention period, but if you have data flowing all the time that should not be your case. It would be good to check if DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS and MAX_DATA_EXTENSION_TIME_IN_DAYS have been changed. Another potential thing is recreation of the source table (via CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE) will cause the stream to become stable.

Comment: Are you merging from the table or the stream as the source?  It sounds like your DML isn't leveraging the stream, so the offset isn't moving.  After you hit your data retention period, it becomes stale.  That's just speculation based on the symptoms, so providing more details around your MERGE code, your STREAM definition would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that we had some direct castings like `::int` in the script. After a while developers started sending strings in the JSON data. The stream contained several scripts encapsulated in `begin..commit`. The task did not show the scripts failed but in reality, the DML statements were rolled back so the stream did not clear. Eventually, they became stale as the data was not cleared within the default timeframe. We changed any `x::int` to `try_to_number(x::string)` and this worked.